# Aligning a transparent PNG over same-colored CSS background

Tags: css, png, transparency, colors

My idea is that a PNG overlaying some text, with transparency ranging from 0% to 100%, all colored in the same color as the CSS background, would fade out the text underlying it.

Turns out the transparent PNG is visible also in the areas where it's supposed to be transparent. Also, the colors of the PNG and the CSS are not the same - even though I create them with the same hex-values.

An image is included. I have tried creating the resource in Illustrator, Photoshop and Fireworks. I have tried removing the gamma-information (gAMA) with pngcrush, PNGSquash and ImageMagick. The problem is the same on Firefox as in Safari.

If anyone knows how to solve this -- or if it's even possible -- I'd love to hear it! Thank you in advance.

[image: the gradient is visible even though transparent]

Comment: Oh, I meant to ask in my comment below, but could you post your code (xhtml/css) and -if possible- link to a live demo that shows what you've got so far?

Answer (score 2):

I can't immediately solve the issue you're experiencing, but I can offer an alternative text-fading solution, if that's of any use?

```
.text-to-fade {color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0) /* red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0 */
               }
```

the value of `0.0` at the end is the alpha value, and can range from `0` to `1`, with `0` being opaque and `1` being transparent. `rgba` has problems on browsers other than Firefox insofar as I've experimented.

perhaps

```
.text-to-fade {opacity: 0.5; /* for most browsers */
               filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* for IE */
               }
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that CSS. However, if I understand correctly, this could only create a text-fading-out effect if I would apply it repeated times with different alpha-values to the bottom 3/4/5/? rows of text?

What I'm trying to solve is to fade out the text without having to code some logic that counts rows -- because the number of rows could be "anything" due to dynamic content.

Comment: Wouldn't the same problem occur if you use a .png floated over those rows? I'd love to amend my answer and offer a JS/jQuery solution (which would be necessary to amend the CSS values). I'll try and see if I can find a better solution more in keeping with your request.

Comment: I would be very happy with any suggestion! However I'm not too familiar with JS/jQuery. But that's no reason not to learn :)

Comment: Yeah, me neither...I keep trying, it keeps hurting my brain for some reason... =)

Comment: I just saw your other comment. You can view the site in action at http://eferm.com, where the PNG is in usage. 

If you find something, let me know! I'll keep trying myself too.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it appears to be a different color is because it's transparent, not because the colors are actually different. To demonstrate this, open an image editor that supports layers. Create a white bottom layer and a black top layer. Set the opacity of the black layer to 50% and merge the layers down. Use a color picker to check the color. It's going to be #808080, not black.

The reason it's not fading is because that color is additive. Say your text is #808080 too: in places where there's text, you have #808080 overlaying #808080--and that ends up being something like #424242 rather than canceling out as you want. There's really not a great way to do what you're trying to do inside a web browser in only one step.

One thing to do would be to make the text invisible (visibility: hidden;) with javascript. Another option would be to use relative or absolute positioning and set up the z-indices so things look something like this:

- 3: TRANSPARENT-GREY
- 2: button/any other objects
- 1: OPAQUE-GREY
- 0: text

That will block out the text and leave anything else partially visible.

Comment: Ah... I somehow understand. Thank you for the description! However, it seems like I'm left to implement code that senses what row certain words in a paragraph end up in... But that's a different problem.